# Assign related product to multiple simple products in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I am using Magento CE 1.8. 
I want to assign same products as related product to 50 simple products in magento. Is there any way to do it in bulk?

Answer (score 1):

In order to set related you need to do the following
Let's assume that the current product is $_product (that you got by doing `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(SOME ID))`

```
$_product->setRelatedLinkData($param);
```

`$param` is an array with the following structure

```
$param = array(
$associatedProductId=>array(
'position'=>$associatedProductPosition
)
)
```

Here is an example. Let's say you want to add products with ids 101 and 102 as related products to $_product on positions 3 and 5.
You should do something like this:

```
$param = array(
101=>array(
'position'=>3
),
102=>array(
'position'=>5
)
);
$_product->setRelatedLinkData($param);
//here ... some other product operations and in the end
$_product->save();
```

Use the `foreach` and add/modify in between the above code.

I hope this will help you to achieve what you want.

**CREDIT:** `http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.in/2010/06/adding-related-products-up-sells-and.html`

For more information check following link.

> http://magentotutorial.in/how-to-add-related-products-in-magento-by-code-script/